# What to do when IDENTITY column has been exhausted

Tags: sql-server

How to reseed identity column in SQL when you have existing data ? Is there an easy way to perform this operation so that all data get updated identities (which are reflected on associations foreign keys aswell) ?

EDIT: What happen if you reach the limit of your identity column ? What would you do in that case ? that why i asked this question. I just want to understand how this kind of problem can be solved.

Comment: For what possible purpose? If it's because you don't like gaps or large numbers, then *stop using IDENTITY*.

Comment: It's messy.  Do you have unique constraints (not related to the IDENTITY) on all the tables?

Comment: But yeah........just because "you might be able to pull it off"..........doesn't mean its a good idea.

Comment: I will edit my question...

Comment: What happen if you reach the limit of your identity column ? What would you do in that case ? that why i asked this question. I just want to understand how this kind of problem can be solved.

Comment: Then ask THAT question.

Comment: @Rushino -- assuming you're using an integer, and you hit a value greater than 2,147,483,647, just `ALTER` the primary key to be a bigint instead.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables well, it's a little more involved than that. Try altering a column that is participating in a PK and has FKs pointed at it. You need to remove all of the constraints first.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - true, I did oversimplify it.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically. You could write you own set of scripts to get this done, but I am not aware of any comercial (MS or other) solution that would "compress" an existing identity range. But, as Aaron said, why would you want to do this in the first place?

SQL Server's identity values are not guaranteed to be free of gaps or even monotonically growing. For more details check out http://sqlity.net/en/792/the-gap-in-the-identity-value-sequence/

If you need your values to be monotonically growing or continuous you might have to develop your own "value provider service".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible HACK solution.

Did you start at "0" with the original IDENTITY definition.

You have a whole -MAX to -1 at your disposal.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTableName', RESEED, -2147483648);
```

BUT, you could have application code (ex: DotNet) that checks for things like "if myKey>0" that would bl0w up.

If you did this, I would put an extra CHECK constraint that would fail once the table hit -1.

Again, I do not really suggest it.  But offer it as a possibilty.

The few times I've used IDENTITY (since the "old days"), I actually start the seeding at the -MAX value.

One example.  A logging table that had no FK under it.  Just a table to throw some audit data that got flushed every week, so it didn't actually matter.  The IDENTITY simply gave it some order.

Answer (score -1):

By using [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx), you can provide the `RESEED` parameter and a `new_reseed_value` as in the example below (from the MSDN link):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("Person.AddressType", RESEED, 10);
GO
```

Combine with UPDATE and [IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) to modify existing data.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to change the existing identity values, not the next one.

Comment: You'd need to modify both existing AND next identities for it to work, especially if you're increasing the value.